# Translating JavaScript formula

Tags: javascript, math

[image]

I tried like that `K *  i/12 / 1 - Math.pow((1+( i/12)), -n)`

Comment: Use parentheses to group the sub-expressions as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
const f = (k, i, n) => k * (
  (i / 12) /
  (1 - Math.pow(1 + (i/12), -n))
)
```

Liberally apply parenthesis to make it unambiguous